# How can I clear SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation after migration?

Tags: migration, magento2.2.6

I am trying to migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2.2.6 using Cart2Cart. Everything comes over but I get errors like the one below when I try to reindex.

```
Category Products indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'1-510' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO 
`temp_catalog_category_tree_index_22f595b8` (`parent_id`,`child_id`) 
VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), 
(?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, 
?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), 
(?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, 
?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)
Product Categories indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'1-510' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO 
`temp_catalog_category_tree_index_ae4a77f3` (`parent_id`,`child_id`) 
VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), 
(?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, 
?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), 
(?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, 
?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)
```

In trying to do more research I try to find the temp_catalog_category_tree_index_22f595b8 and it doesn't exist. I then look for just catalog_category_tree and it doesn't exist either. Where and how can I clear this error?

Comment: Why are you using Cart2Cart? The official magento 2 migration tool is free and is more reliable.

Comment: @KonstantinGerasimov My code is done, I only need to migrate products, orders, and customers. The data migration tool brings over a lot of stuff I don't want it to, but also I am unsure on how to clear the existing info to bring it over.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248341/getting-an-error-in-indexing-after-migration-in-magento-2-2-6 View this, this worked for me.